# Looking for a direct opposite of modulo or % in C programming

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

Built a C program that encrypts things using a Caesar Cipher. It converts it to an alphabetic number (0 = a / 1 = b / 2 = c) and then converts it pack after moving by the number of characters specified by using a modulo operator. I am currently trying to build a program the decrypts it and I need the exact opposite of a modulo operator to invert the sequence.

Comment: There is no opposite to modulo. Modulo maps multiple inputs to the same output, there's no way to know which input it originally was.

Comment: E.g. `30 % 26` and `56 % 26` both result in `4`, there's no way to recover the original.

Comment: " I am currently trying to build a program the decrypts it " --> post that code.

Comment: It seems your question has been answered, but if you need a helpful reference/ double check when you're all done, a copy of my working caesar cypher can be found [here](https://github.com/christopherdiehl/BlogPosts/blob/master/caesarCypher.c)

Comment: Modulo is a one-way function. There is no reverse function for it.

Comment: Reverse modulo? That sounds a bit like taking a burger and trying to retrieve the cow.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to invert a Caesar cipher, you are not looking for the inverse of the modulo operator.

If your encryption is

```
int encrypt(int plaintext, int shift){
    int ciphertext = (plaintext + shift) % 26;
    return ciphertext;
}
```

Then decryption is

```
int decrypt(int ciphertext, int shift){
    int plaintext = (ciphertext - shift + 26) % 26;
    return plaintext;
}
```

for whatever your choice of `shift` was for encryption.

Comment: can you define exactly what you are using for C and P? (I am using e = (e + k)%26) and am just moving down the line with E as so I don't trip over variables

Comment: Absolutely also double checked the math my self and found it to be 100% solid. I must have a messed up implementation in some place. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I had been testing it and while using small numbers it works wonderfully however when I put in a key such as 467467 it butchers the output and sends back a totally different string

Comment: @JackDavies please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*.

Comment: Note that the actual input to `encrypt` and `decrypt` is a number in the range of `[0, 26)`. The number represents a (plain or cipher) letter of the alphabet.